# Regex match comments (single-line or multiple-line) and match everything else (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm working with C# and I want to match **single-line comments** or *multiple-line comments* or **everything** else.
for example the text below:

```
/* 
this
is a multiple-line
comment */

this = "is code";

// this is a single-line comment
```

Right now I'm using this regex `/{2}(?<single>.*?)$|/\*(?<multiple>.*?)\*/`

The matching modes are **single-line** | **multiple-line**.

This is good for matching the comments but it doesn't match general code.

I tried this:

`/{2}(?<single>.*?)$|/\*(?<multiple>.*?)\*/|(?<code>.*)`

to match the code but it seems to mess with the other captures (I though it would only capture code if none of the other capture groups worked).

Comment: This is good enough for you, just split with the comment regex ad you will get the rest.

Comment: I do understand want you are saying ;) but i wanted them to stay in the corresponding groups... and split doesn't maintain the group names or is there a way?

Comment: Parse the code with the right tool, use the dedicated C# code parser. Regex will not be safe to use, it will certainly fail in edge cases.

Comment: @xDGameStudios like @WiktorStribiżew said: `string url = "http://example.com"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but I don't want to parse C# I want to parse a bunch of files that use a "custom" language (not created by me)... and I don't have to check for errors, nor compile it, nor run it... I just need to make some edits for example remove all comments... or remove all macro definitions or after removing macro definitions if text is empty ignore the file all together.

Comment: So, you need that language parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay then.. thank you :) I'll look into that.. I was just trying to avoid having to build a parser just for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple regular expression which will match both multi-line and single-line comments (C-style): `((\/[*])([\s\S]+)([*]\/))|([/]{2,}[^\n]+)`

To use this in C#:

```
int Foo(string haystack) {
    var regex = new Regex(@"((\/[*])([\s\S]+)([*]\/))|([/]{2,}[^\n]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    var matches = regex.Match(haystack);

    return matches.Count; 
}
```

I'm not too sure what you mean with "match everything else", because that's not really what RegEx is for - you could just as well take the entire text.
What you can (and possibly should) do, is match comments in the code and then ignore your matches when it comes to the rest of the code.

If you're interested in matching code constructs, you'd have to create a regular expression for each one.
Here's one for if/else: `(if)|(else)` - you could then use the matches to do whatever you intend. 
This would match strings (double-quoted): `(["][^"]+["])`

Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, but if you just want to split the comments, get your matches and ignore the rest - or invert the match.

Comment: Nope. No idea what you mean.

Comment: It fails against that string.

Comment: Tested here: regexr.com/4pphs. Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Regex for both
/* multiline
comments */
and
// single comments

```
string clear = new Regex(@"((\/[*])([\s\S]+?)([*]\/))|([/]{2,}[^\n]+)").Replace(input, "");
```